# How can I use a url parameter(that is a user id <str:pk>) to prepopulate a field in DJANGO form

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-forms

I'm doing a management application with 2 pages: users(clientes) and a user datail page that contains a user payment history(cheques).

I'm trying to do a create a form in payment history page(cheques.html) to add a new payment, but I'd the Cheque.cliente would be equals to the current user URL. Ex.: if your URL is cheque/5/, the Cheque.cliente should be 5, and when I add a new payment, the payment should be tracked(ForeignKey) to the user 5(each user has many payments).

Resuming: This application has the functions to CRUD all the user(clientes) and all the payments(cheques), but only the add payment(cheque) function isn't working.

**VIEWS.py**

```
#CLIENTES
def index(request):
    clientes = Cliente.objects.all()
    
    form = ClienteForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'clientes':clientes, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'clientes/home.html', context)

#CHEQUES
#THE ERROR IS IN THIS VIEW!
def chequesCliente(request, pk):
    cheques = Cheque.objects.filter(id=pk)
    nome = Cliente.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    formc = ChequeForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formc = ChequeForm(request.POST)
        print(formc.data['cliente'])
        if formc.is_valid():
            print(formc.cleaned_data)
            formc.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'cheques':cheques, 'formc':formc, 'nome':nome,}
    return render(request, 'clientes/cheques.html', context)

def updateCheque(request, pk):
    cheque = Cheque.objects.get(id=pk)

    formc = ChequeForm(instance=cheque)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formc = ChequeForm(request.POST, instance=cheque)
        if formc.is_valid():
            formc.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'formc':formc}
    return render(request, 'clientes/update_cheque.html', context)

def deleteCheque(request, pk):
    item = Cheque.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        item.delete()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'item':item}
    return render(request, 'clientes/delete_cheque.html', context)
```

**URLS.py**

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='lista'),
    path('update/<str:pk>/', views.updateCliente, name="update"),
    path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteCliente, name="delete"),
    path('cheques/<str:pk>/', views.chequesCliente, name="lista_cheques"),
    #cliente/CRUD/num_cheque
    path('update_cheque/<str:pk>/', views.updateCheque, name="update_cheque"),
    path('delete_cheque/<str:pk>/', views.deleteCheque, name="delete_cheque"),
]
```

**MODELS.py**

```
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    num = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    limite = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    situacao = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
class Cheque(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cheques')
    banco = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    numero = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    emissao = models.DateField()
    vencimento = models.DateField()
    sem_fundos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.banco
```

**FORMS.py**

```
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = '__all__'
class ChequeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cheque
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['cliente',]
```

**TEMPLATES_cheques.HTML**

```
        <div id="flex_subheader">  
          <button type="button" class="my_btn" id="retornar" onclick="location.href='{% url 'clientes:lista' %}'"><span>Retornar</span></button>
          <h2>{{ nome }}</h2></div>
        <div id="adicionar_cheque" class="criar">
          <form method="post" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formc.non_field_errors }}
            <table>
            {{ formc.as_table }}
            <input type="submit" id="sub_cheque" value="Confirmar!">
            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Banco</th>
                <th scope="col">Número</th>
                <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                <th scope="col">Emissão</th>
                <th scope="col">Vencimento</th>
                <th scope="col">Sem Fundos</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for cheque in cheques %}
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{ cheque.pk }}</th>
                  <td>{{ cheque.banco }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cheque.numero }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cheque.valor }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cheque.emissao }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cheque.vencimento }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cheque.sem_fundos }}</td>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'clientes:update_cheque' cheque.id %}" class="my_btn" id="editar">Editar</a></td>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'clientes:delete_cheque' cheque.pk %}" class="my_btn" id="excluir">Excluir</a></td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </section>
```

**TEMPLATES_clientes.html**

```
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{ cliente.pk }}</th>
                  <td> <a href="{% url 'clientes:lista_cheques' cliente.id %}"> {{ cliente.nome }} </a></td>
                  <td>{{ cliente.cpf }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cliente.num }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cliente.endereco }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cliente.cidade }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cliente.limite }}</td>
                  <td>{{ cliente.situacao }}</td>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'clientes:update' cliente.id %}" class="my_btn" id="editar">Editar</a></td>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'clientes:delete' cliente.id %}" class="my_btn" id="excluir">Excluir</a></td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you want to prepopulate the field (which allows the POST request to potentially have a different value, eg due to the user choosing a different option) or do you want to automatically set it without allowing the user to potentially change it?

Comment: The second one: I don't want to allow the user to change it.

Comment: Then the approach sketched out in the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777286/2337736) is the best - don't have that field in the form, just assign it on the uncommitted object before saving. Note that you can't necessarily trust the value from the URI either, users can edit that and reload. I'd probably get a user ID from the request object if using the built in authentication system if it needs to be even vaguely secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving the form, you can add the parameter commit=False. This will create a objects of the submitted data, but not save it in the database (no primary key exists). On the object you can alter data and when you are done, save the object:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False) # returns an instance of a model object without pk
    obj.field1 = some_value
    obj.save() # Save the object to the db
```

Comment: Alright, and how can I atribute to the some_value the current URL? Is it going to be obj.field1 = pk?

Comment: Yes, the value captured from the URL will be available in the pk argument to the view. You've declared it as a string in your urls.py, so to use it as a PK you'll need to convert it to an integer first. Or, better, update your urls.py to expect an int so you can trust that it doesn't match eg `/cheque/foobar`.

Comment: When using a primary key in the URL, my first line is always, obj = get_object_or_404(Model, id=id). If I declare the primary key in the URL, I'm sure I need the object it points to.